# 0 SUPPORTED DEVICES for Android APK Release

Tags: android, apk

I have an apk on Google Play which says that it has 0 supported devices. I tried to put all the features on false, but still no effect.

This is what Google says when I upload the apk:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uso3N.jpg)

The code below is what I have in manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dentasoft.admin"
   >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="false"/>

    <!-- Indicates use of Android's VR-mode, available only on Android N+. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="false"/>
    <!-- Indicates use of VR features that are available only on Daydream-ready devices. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="false"/>


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity android:name=".tickets.TicketViewActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tickets.TicketActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tickets"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LogIn"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messenger.Messenger"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_messenger" />
        <activity
            android:name=".scanner.ActivityScanner"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scanner"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".scanner.ActivityScannerResult"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scanner_result">

        </activity>

        <!--<activity-->
        <!--android:name=".scanner.status.ActivityPopUpStatus"-->
        <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupTheme"/>-->

        <activity android:name=".tickets.NewTicketActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupTheme"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Starter"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".history.CommandListActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Notifications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
            />

        <activity android:name=".history.SearchPopupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupTheme"/>

        <activity android:name=".scanner.stl.StlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl"
                    android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/stl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-stl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:scheme="content"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".scanner.stl.gvr.ModelGvrActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:enableVrMode="@string/gvr_vr_mode_component"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <!--
                 The VR icon to be used in Daydream Home comes in two parts:
                 a foreground icon and a background icon.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/vr_icon" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon_background"
                android:resource="@drawable/vr_icon_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />

                <!--
                     The DAYDREAM category should only be declared by Activities that are Daydream
                     compatible. Daydream compatible apps should typically use the Daydream
                     controller APIs directly, however in this sample app we instead rely on
                     Cardboard trigger emulation.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.DAYDREAM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".floating_heads.ChatHeadService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".notifications.NotificationListener"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I verified the gradle file and I don't have the problem with 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.+' compilation.

Comment: Did you already published the app? I had the same issue once. All supported devices appeared after publishing.

Comment: most activities lack the `intent-filter`... and screen sizes are not explicitly defined.

Comment: @ZhebzhikBabich I have already published the app, but on Device Catalog still writes 0 Devices supported

Comment: @MartinZeitler I will try to fix that just hoping that it should resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** (Answer received from Google Support)

The line

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
```

is not supported by any device.